# Zen Coding with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, emmet

Is it possible to write your HTML with Zen Coding expressions into your CSHTML?  Say, something like

```
`foreeach(var str in list)

    {
          table>(tr>td[str])
    }
```

where you can use C# variables in your HTML coding while writing Zen code stuff?

Comment: you mean non expanding zen coding expressions that expand on compilation? no.  and even in your example you run into problems, I'm taking it what you really meant was make a new row for each str, but the way it is, it makes a whole new table for each str.  To get what you want you'd really need razor to support the syntax, or something that does your syntax -> razor

Comment: That what I was afraid of.

Comment: there's plenty of zen coding text expansion plugins though

Answer (score 1):

If you install most popular extension for web development in visual studio 
**Web Essentials** you will get Zen coding enabled.
You can install this via NuGet.
http://vswebessentials.com/

> ZenCoding with #WebEssentials is a sweet productivity enhancement! CSS as a template language for expansion is awesome!